# Why duplicate folders in an Android project?

Tags: android-studio, testing

I've found out that over a course of several years, a lot of programs keep seemingly duplicate "project folders" in the Android Studio, why is that?

To elaborate a bit further, if you import their projects, and if you take a look at  there folder structure, there is going to be something like this:

Java

|--com.myproject.spaceInvader

|--com.myproject.spaceInvader(test)

|--com.myproject.spaceInvader(alphaTest)

What are these? Something generated by 3rd party testing tools?

Comment: They're not duplicate folders. Look at the project view or in a file manager and you'll see they're three different source sets.

Comment: You can have a look at https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/

These folder is for unit testing and android instrumentation testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a project in Android Studio, it has a [standard structure](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/):

[image: A tipical project's structure]

From [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/):

**main**

> Contains the "main" sourceset files: the Android code and
>   resources shared by all build variants (files for other build variants
>   reside in sibling directories, such as src/debug/ for the debug build
>   type). AndroidManifest.xml Describes the nature of the application and
>   each of its components. For more information, see the
>   AndroidManifest.xml documentation. java/ Contains Java code sources.

**test**

> Contains code for local tests that run on your host JVM.

**androidTest**

> Contains code for instrumentation tests that run on an
>   Android device. For more information, see the Android Test
>   documentation.